# Book about multiply resurrected soldiers and 2cm wide matter transfer gate

Tags: story-identification, books

Trying to recall title of a book from at least 20 yrs ago about a soldier in an army (UN force?) where fighters were regularly suicided and multiply resurrected.

They also trained for paranoia (i.e. always looking for ways to kill everyone including their own command). Resurrection was using gloop made from failed solders I think.

Also included a matter transmitter system that was limited to 2 cm gates or else triggered supernovas (previous usage unaware had caused ~ 10% of stars to go nova). So travel required users being minced to fit and then resurrected on the receiving side.

Answer (score 20):

*The Space Eater* (1982) by David Langford?

From [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1930997795):

> DEATH WILL NOT RELEASE YOU **Ken Jacklin is a soldier who has died many times.** Rossa Corman has a communications talent that depends on pain. Together they must make an excruciating journey via **makeshift matter transmitter** and persuade a distrustful, war-torn planetary colony to halt research into Anomalous Physics -- the maverick science whose side effects include continent-busting nullbombs, exploding suns, and a mysterious final weapon called the Devourer. Gradually Jacklin and Corman realize that what Earth has told them about their own mission is a labyrinth of bluff and lies.... A high-tension hard SF thriller.

[This review](https://paradoxolbers.wordpress.com/2008/01/) mentions the two (well, 1.933) centimeters gates and the main character dying over and over again:

> If you go to my “About Paradox and Spike” page, you’ll see my interest in “hard science” sf; so why am I remembering and recommending a story about a “Force zombie killer?”  Because **Forceman Ken Jacklin, fighting to keep order in a war-torn London, has died 46 times and has gotten used to dying in combat**, although he doesn’t have an interest in anything else any more … [...]
>
> What remains of the government picks Jacklin to go to the one stellar colony to prevent them from making AP/Anomalous Physics experiments themselves.  **To get there, he and the tele(pathic)com officer will go through an AP gate – 1.933 centimeters wide** …

---

Found with the Google query `scifi book transfer gate "centimeters wide"` which returned the above review.

Comment: If this is the right answer, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark on the left.

Comment: _transmitter system that was limited to 2 cm gates_ That must be the Transfer Gate of Amigara Fault. How is it supposed to look in free space? Wouldn't one state a ... maximal radius?

Comment: I think it's usually stated within the story as a diameter in order to make it sound bigger. That review is accurate and the book was first published in 1982.